# Replacing specific numbers with String.Replace or Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Just having a little problem in attempting a string or regex replace on specific numbers in a string.

For example, in the string

```
@1 is having lunch with @10 @11
```

I would like to replace "@1", "@10" and "@11" with the respective values as indicated below.

```
"@1" replace with "@bob"
"@10" replace with "@joe"
"@11" replace with "@sam"
```

So the final output would look like

```
"@bob is having lunch with @joe @sam"
```

Attempts with

```
String.Replace("@1", "@bob")
```

results in the following

```
@bob is having lunch with @bob0 @bob1
```

Any thoughts on what the solution might be?

Comment: Are you restricted to the @<number> format? Furthermore, do you determine what the numbers are?

Comment: I would recommend that the answers not rely on the assumption that there will be a space after `@1`. Usually, code that does this sort of thing should not know or care about the content of the string where the replacements are being made. In my opinion, it should work, regardless of whether `@1` is followed by a space, comma, period, semi-colon, or other punctuation. I think a fair assumption to make would be that the "parameters" (`@1`, `@10`, and `@11`) are not followed immediately by any alpha characters, although that would be for the asker to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all placeholder start with `@` and contain only digits, you can use the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload that accepts a MatchEvaluator delegate to pick the replacement value from a dictionary:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"@\d+");

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"@1","@bob"},
    {"@10","@joe"},
    {"@11","@sam"},
};

var input = "@1 is having lunch with @10 @11";
var result=regex.Replace(input, m => dict[m.Value]);
```

The result will be `"@bob is having lunch with @joe @sam"`

There are a few advantages compared to multiple `String.Replace` calls:

1. The code is more concise, for an arbitrary number of placeholders
2. You avoid mistakes due to the order of the replacements (eg `@11` must come before `@1`)
3. It's faster because you don't need to search and replace the placeholders multiple times
4. It doesn't create temporary strings for each parameter. This can be an issue for server applications because a large number of orphaned strings will put pressure on the garbage collector

The reason for advantages 3-4 is that the regex will parse the input and create an internal representation that contains the indexes for any match. When the time comes to create the final string, it uses a StringBuilder to read characters from the original string but substitute the replacement values when a match is encountered.

Comment: This seems a more elegant solution and has worked so far with the test data we have. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer more declarative way of doing this. What if there will be another replacements, for example `@2` change to `luke`? You will have to change the code (add another `Replace` call).

My proposition with declarations of the replacements:

```
string input = "@1 is having lunch with @10 @11";
var rules = new Dictionary<string,string>() 
{
    { "@1", "@bob" },
    { "@10", "@joe" },
    { "@11", "@sam"}
};

string output = Regex.Replace(input, 
                              @"@\d+", 
                              match => rules[match.Value]);
```

*Explanation:*

Regular expression is searching for pattern `@\d+` which means `@` followed by one or more digits. And replaces this match thanks to `MatchEvaluator` by the proper entry from the `rules` dictionary, where the key is the match value itself.

Comment: The rules should be applied in the order ("@11 -> @sam" before "@1 -> @bob") and Dictionary doesn't preserve the order. It seems, that you have to use `List<Tuple<String, String>>` or alike

Comment: @DmitryBychenko there's no need to apply any order. Unlike repeated `String.Replace` calls, this regex will match each placeholder exactly and replace them in one go

Comment: There's no need for checking the groupings, `match.Value` already contains the placeholder text

Answer (score 1):

Start with the biggest (read longest) number like @11 and @10 first and then replace @1.

```
string finalstring = mystring.Replace("@11", "@sam")
                             .Replace("@10", "@joe")
                             .Replace("@1", "@bob");
```

Comment: I think its important to put emphasis on the bigger numbers first.

Comment: You should start with the longest, not the "biggest" number (is `@2` bigger than `@10`?). The actual ordering of the parameters doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Make your regular expression look for the string @1_

The space after will ensure that it only gets the number @1.